# ¿Por qué me informa que no existe la localStorage en React cuando uso el servicio?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Cuando hago **login** de usuario en mi **componente Login**, con un **servicio** le envio el **email** y **password** a **node/express**, y si los datos son correctos, me devuelve el **token** y el **email** del usuario.
Desde **React** tomo el **token** y **email**, el **email** lo guardo en la **localStorage**, y **redirijo a la pagina Home**.
pero, como mi pagina **Home** esta **protegida**, antes de redirigir pregunto en el archivo **protected**, si la **localStorage** existe.
Si existe retorna a **home**, caso contrario redirige a **login**. Pero me informa que no existe la **localStorage**.

Aca el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aca **login**:

```js
const onSubmit = async (data, e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let authService = new AuthService();
    // se activa el spinner/loader
    setLoading(true);
    const result = authService.login(data);
    result.then((res) => {
      setLoading(false);
      console.log('email: ' + res.email);
      console.log('token: ' + res.token);
      localStorage.setItem("user", res.email);
      window.location.reload(history.push("/home"));
    });
  };
```

aca el **servicio**

```js
import axios from "axios";

class AuthService {
  async login(user) {
    try {
      let res = await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/api/auth/login", user);
      const data = res.data;
      return data;
    } catch (e) {
      alert("Error login de usuario");
    }
  }
}
export default AuthService;
```

aca **App.js** con el **ruteo protejido**

```js
import Protected from "./components/auth/Protected"

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";


function App() {

  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <div className="box">
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Protected Cmp={Home} />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/home">
          <Protected Cmp={Home} />
        </Route> 
        
        <Route path="/createOperation">
          <Protected Cmp={CreateOperation} />
        </Route>
        
        <Route path="/login" component={Login}></Route>
      
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
   
  );
}

export default App;
```

aca el archivo **protected** (el que comprueba si la localStorage existe)

```js
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"

function Protected(props){
    let Cmp = props.Cmp;
    const history = useHistory();

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!localStorage.getItem("user")){
            alert('no existe localStorage user')
            history.push("/login")
        }
    }, [])

    return(
        <div>
           <Cmp />
        </div>    
    );
}

export default Protected;
```

**Si funciona, si no utilizo el servicio en el Login y hago todo directamente asi:**

```js
const onSubmit = async (data, e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // se activa el spinner/loader
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const result = await axios
        .post("http://localhost:4000/api/auth/login", data)
        .then((res) => {
          const email = data.email; // value del input email
          const token = res.data.token;
          alert('TOKEN: ' + token);
          localStorage.setItem("user", email);
          window.location.reload(history.push("/home"));
        });
    } catch (e) {
      setLoading(false);
      alert("Error login de usuario");
    }
  };
```

Comment: ¿Puedes probar haciendo la redirección en Protected  con un render condicional (en vez de usar un hook)? Algo cómo `return( <div> { localStorage.getItem("user") ?  <Cmp />:<Redirect to="login"/>}</div>     );` Tendrías que importar `Redirect` de `react-router`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te das cuenta cuando te funciona sin el servicio le pones await para invocar  al servicio, sin embargo, cuando llamas al login que es async no le haces await, por lo tanto, hay una desincronización.  Utiliza  result = await login(). Al retornar result recibirá la data  por lo que no es  necesario hacer  el result.then(). El await en este caso esta haciendo la función del .then.

Answer (score -1):

localStorage devuelve una promesa,
si queres validar si existe **user**
deberías hacer algo asi:

```
localStorage.getItem(user)
.then(user => {
   if(!user) {
    // do something
   }
})
```

o usando async await, queda a tu gusto.

localStorage existe en los browsers independientemente del framework/lib que uses.

Comment: gracias por responder, en el archivo "protected" hice esto : localStorage.getItem("user").then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        history.push("/login")
      }
    });

Comment: Pero sale este error: CANNOT READ PROPERTY THEN OF NULL

Comment: No conozco mucho el reactjs pero al menos puedo seguir la lógica. si te das cuenta cuando te funciona sin el servicio le pones await, sin embargo, cuando, llamas al login que es async no le haces await. Para mí es falta de sincronización. ¿no se puede  setear el localstoragen en el servicio? El error es el mismo no existe user.

Comment: Me confundi con AsyncStorage de React Native...

lo que estas haciendo está perfecto @Claudio , en el caso de que user no existe debería retornar null, podes probar haciendo:

`
if (localStorage.getItem("user") === null) {
  //...do something
}
`

Comment: @Juan Carlos Guibovich, es que si agrego el await como vos decis, es decir: const result = await authService.login(data); me muestra este error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): result.then is not a function

Comment: Es que  no utilices el .then puesto que al retornar  await login() result ya tiene la data que recibió y no necesitas  hacer un .then. El await en este caso esta haciendo la función del .then.

Comment: gracias @Juan Carlos Guibovich! ahora si  funciona. comparto la solucion en mi publicacion.

Comment: Entonces, te pongo  mis comentarios  como  solución.

Comment: si mejor asi te valido la respuesta.